# I am trying to add checkbox for anonymous post on form post

Tags: forms, posting

i wanna add new feature on my wordpress site 
post as anonymously
i tried to customize the form field and add a new field and the database
but there are too files and instruction to store form data in the data base and not found how to custom wordpress code .

please can anyone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't ever edit core files. Your changes will be lost on update. WordPress has a great way to expand as needed called [Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

As you don't have enough knowledge about how WordPress works I suggest to use this ready made solution to avoid any risk. Here is the [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accesspress-anonymous-post/)

Comment: Thanks Sabbir,

I know it's not easy to customize code for it.

but i'm searching on someway to do it, because there is no plugin to do this actually and you link just to allow users posting as logged out without any checkbox or options!

Comment: If you can be more specific about your requirement then I'm sure I can help. Let me know few things. 
1. How you illustrate the front website for anonymous post?
2. Do user have to login to post?